# When trying to set stableIds to recyclerview adapter, I get error that my adapter has registered observers

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to achieve some animations when sorting my recyclerview and read that easy way of implementing this is setting "hasStableIds" to true to recyclerview adapter. 
When I set it to true, I get an error`Cannot change whether this adapter has stable IDs while the adapter has registered observers.` . I didn't set any observers to my adapter. Is there something else that could cause this error?

My recyclerview is inside fragment and I inicialize it like this

```
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),SeznamManager.getSeznam(),recyclerView,FragmentSeznam.this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
```

I am using custom RecyclerViewAdapter with custom ViewHolder, might that be the cause of problem?

I also override the GetItemId method which is required when trying to setStableIds

```
   @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
    Polozka polozka = mPolozky.get(position);
    return polozka.getNazev().hashCode();
}
```

If you have any idea what's wrong, I would be more than glad to hear it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have to Override hasStableIds to return true.

```
if (!adapter.hasObservers()) {
    adapter.setHasStableIds(true)
}
```

then

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
Polozka polozka = mPolozky.get(position);
return (polozka.getNazev()+polozka.getothermethod()....).hashCode();
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this only dodge an error and not actually set StableIds to true?

Comment: add all methods in pojo class then convert into hashcode.check edited answer.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I added all get methods from pojo class and converted it to hashcode. The "adapter.setHasStableIds(true); still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution.

Remove getItemViewType method from recyclerViewAdapter if you have one as it's what was causing the trouble!

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this workaround which sorted the issue for me.

```
if (!adapter.hasObservers()) {
    adapter.setHasStableIds(true)
}
```